# Hyper key showing as Super key

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to use the hyper key in Emacs.  Have changed the keyboard layout to `Generic 101-key PC` and am doing this check to determine whether keycode 66 is associated with the Hyper key.

```
actm=$(xmodmap -pke | grep "Hyper" | grep "66")
```

But when I hit the Hyper key in Emacs, it is showing up as the Super key.

Have used `xev` on the Hyper key and get

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5400001,
   root 0x16a, subw 0x0, time 17997615, (79,39), root:(1257,1320),
   state 0x0, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffed, Hyper_L), same_screen YES,
   XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
   XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
   XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How can I get Emacs to consider the key as Hyper rather than Super?